# Running Python on MAMP or Linux/cPanel

Tags: python, linux, twitter

I'm trying to setup a Python Twitter bot on MAMP and/or a Linux VPS

The Twitter bot script is here: https://github.com/rhiever/twitter-follow-bot

How do i go about doing this? When I put it on the servers and go to the destination of the script, It just get the full script in raw text.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly install python on your VPS.

```
sudo apt-get install python
```